# How to read outlook mail from linux terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, outlook-web-access

Normally, I access mail using outlook web-app. Is there any possibility to read my mails from terminal?

May be by setting incoming and outgoing smtp servers. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using alpine on Ubuntu and it works really well.

```
sudo apt-get install -y alpine
```

The first time you launch it, get into to the config / setup section and add your environment specific settings. It is expected to save those in ~/.pinerc.

Website: https://alpineapp.email/

You can view some screenshots here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/130899/how-can-i-configure-alpine-to-read-my-gmail-in-ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

According to [this Microsoft article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/outlook/send-receive-from-app), Outlook.com supports IMAP for remote access, as well as POP3 and SMTP. The servers are:

- IMAP: `imap-mail.outlook.com` (SSL/TLS, i.e. IMAPS)
- POP3: `pop-mail.outlook.com` (SSL/TLS, i.e. POP3S)
- SMTP: `smtp-mail.outlook.com:587` (STARTTLS)

Comment: I do understand that outlook.com provides different ways to access mails. Is it possible to read content of e-mails from linux terminal?